# login time out expired when setting sql server connection

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am a student using SQL Server 2008 in SQL Server authentication mode. Problem is when I try to make an ODBC connection, this msg shows up:

> Connection failed:
>   SQLState:'HYT00'
>   SQL Server Error:0
>   [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver] Login timeout expired

user name, password, server name everything are OK, I've tried enabling TCP/IP and Named Pipes in SQL Server Network Configuration with SQL Server Configuration Manager, but it does not help.

It'll be much appreciated if anyone helps me.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are connecting to the correct instance name if the SQL Browser is turned off, the client won't be able to locate the default instance name.

That is, if you know the instance name you installed to, you should be able to connect with \

If you can post the entire connectionstring, there may be more I can do to assist.